# Gutenberg Shortcode Chooser Block

Tags: shortcode, block-editor

Basically, i want to create a block that shows a popup with the list of my custom post type shortcodes then there should be a link against each shortcode for insertion. Please see attached image of shortcodes that will show up in the popup.

[image]

Comment: This post does not contain a question, unless it is to the effect of "will someone implement this for me," in which case you are unlikely to receive an answer as providing one amounts to free work. Questions should contain a succinct description of a single problem which may be directly addressed without opinion, and include details of whatever your research and attempts are thus far. Please review the "[ask]" page in our [help], and file an [edit] to this question.

Comment: I want to get an idea on how to implement this functionality and do not want actual code.